# AWK / Grep - Exclude lines containing file paths

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I have a .txt file that contains lines with different file paths. I want to simple exclude lines containing certain file paths.
The problem is that I don't get around the regex format that is used with the common tools.

```
sudo cat serv_list.txt | awk '!/C:\\Windows\\system32/' > serv2.txt
sudo cat serv_list.txt | awk '!/"C:\\Windows\\system32"/' > serv2.txt
```

or

```
sudo cat serv_list.txt | grep -a -v "C:\Windows\system32\"
```

I also tried to escape the slashes, but it hasn't worked.

The file looks something like this:

```
Name         PathName                              ProcessId   StartMode
Dhcp         C:\Windows\system32\svchost...        784         Auto
ehRecvr      C:\Windows\ehome\ehRecvr.exe          543         Auto
defragsvc    C:\Windows\system32\svchos...         456         Manual
Audiosrv     C:\Windows\System32\svchost.e..       123         Manual
```

...

The output should be:

```
Name         PathName                              ProcessId   StartMode
ehRecvr      C:\Windows\ehome\ehRecvr.exe          543         Auto
```

...

Can someone please help me on how I have to modify the awk or grep expression to exclude all lines containing the system32 directory path.

Thank you :)

File Extract from Command Line:
[image]

File Extract from Editor:
[image]

Last lines of output:
`cat -v serv_list2.txt`

```
                                               FALSE            Windows Update                                          Normal                   0                      wuauserv                             C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs                                                856                                                0                        Share Process  TRUE           Auto       LocalSystem                  Running                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework  0           Win32_Service      Manages user-mode driver host processes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 FALSE            Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework  Normal                   1077                   wudfsvc                              C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted                           0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     LocalSystem                  Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       WWAN AutoConfig                                         0           Win32_Service      This service manages mobile broadband (GSM & CDMA) data card/embedded module adapters and connections by auto-configuring the networks. It is strongly recommended that this service be kept running for best user experience of mobile broadband devices.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               FALSE            WWAN AutoConfig                                         Normal                   1077                   WwanSvc                              C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork                                  0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     NT Authority\LocalService    Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
kali@kali:~$
```

Output extract from

```
kali@kali:~$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
($2!~/C:\\Windows\\system32\\/)
' serv_list2.txt
```

```
                                               FALSE            WLAN AutoConfig                                         Normal                   1077                   Wlansvc                              C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted                           0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     LocalSystem                  Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        TRUE        WMI Performance Adapter                                 0           Win32_Service      Provides performance library information from Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) providers to clients on the network. This service only runs when Performance Data Helper is activated.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            FALSE            WMI Performance Adapter                                 Normal                   0                      wmiApSrv                             C:\Windows\system32\wbem\WmiApSrv.exe                                                     1436                                               0                        Own Process    TRUE           Manual     localSystem                  Running                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service            0           Win32_Service      Shares Windows Media Player libraries to other networked players and media devices using Universal Plug and Play                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         FALSE            Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service            Normal                   1077                   WMPNetworkSvc                        "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmpnetwk.exe"                                      0                                                  0                        Own Process    FALSE          Manual     NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService  Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       Parental Controls                                       0           Win32_Service      This service is a stub for Windows Parental Control functionality that existed in Vista. It is provided for backward compatibility only.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 FALSE            Parental Controls                                       Normal                   1077                   WPCSvc                               C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted                          0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     NT Authority\LocalService    Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       Portable Device Enumerator Service                      0           Win32_Service      Enforces group policy for removable mass-storage devices. Enables applications such as Windows Media Player and Image Import Wizard to transfer and synchronize content using removable mass-storage devices.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            FALSE            Portable Device Enumerator Service                      Normal                   0                      WPDBusEnum                           C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted                           0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     LocalSystem                  Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        TRUE        Security Center                                         0           Win32_Service      The WSCSVC (Windows Security Center) service monitors and reports security health settings on the computer.  The health settings include firewall (on/off), antivirus (on/off/out of date), antispyware (on/off/out of date), Windows Update (automatically/manually download and install updates), User Account Control (on/off), and Internet settings (recommended/not recommended). The service provides COM APIs for independent software vendors to register and record the state of their products to the Security Center service.  The Action Center (AC) UI uses the service to provide systray alerts and a graphical view of the security health states in the AC control panel.  Network Access Protection (NAP) uses the service to report the security health states of clients to the NAP Network Policy Server to make network quarantine decisions.  The service also has a public API that allows external consumers to programmatically retrieve the aggregated security health state of the system.  FALSE            Security Center                                         Normal                   0                      wscsvc                               C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted                          784                                                0                        Share Process  TRUE           Auto       NT AUTHORITY\LocalService    Running                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        TRUE        Windows Search                                          0           Win32_Service      Provides content indexing, property caching, and search results for files, e-mail, and other content.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    FALSE            Windows Search                                          Normal                   0                      WSearch                              C:\Windows\system32\SearchIndexer.exe /Embedding                                          2324                                               0                        Own Process    TRUE           Auto       LocalSystem                  Running                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        TRUE        Windows Update                                          0           Win32_Service      Enables the detection, download, and installation of updates for Windows and other programs. If this service is disabled, users of this computer will not be able to use Windows Update or its automatic updating feature, and programs will not be able to use the Windows Update Agent (WUA) API.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      FALSE            Windows Update                                          Normal                   0                      wuauserv                             C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs                                                856                                                0                        Share Process  TRUE           Auto       LocalSystem                  Running                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework  0           Win32_Service      Manages user-mode driver host processes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 FALSE            Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework  Normal                   1077                   wudfsvc                              C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted                           0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     LocalSystem                  Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
FALSE        FALSE       WWAN AutoConfig                                         0           Win32_Service      This service manages mobile broadband (GSM & CDMA) data card/embedded module adapters and connections by auto-configuring the networks. It is strongly recommended that this service be kept running for best user experience of mobile broadband devices.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               FALSE            WWAN AutoConfig                                         Normal                   1077                   WwanSvc                              C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNoNetwork                                  0                                                  0                        Share Process  FALSE          Manual     NT Authority\LocalService    Stopped                      OK       Win32_ComputerSystem     ELS-PC                0       0         
kali@kali:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code, could you please do add samples of input and expected output in your question for better understanding of it, kindly edit your post.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I updated the question. I hope this helps to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '!/[cC]:\\[wW][iI][nN][dD][[oO][wW][sS]\\[sS][yY][sS][tT][eE][mM]32/' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'tolower($0) !~ /c:\\windows\\system32/' Input_file
```

Looks like OP's system doesn't have `IGNORECASE` option so going with above approach where matching small and capita letter both cases for matching.

Didn't know that it would end up here, since OP's samples were keep changing. Or use `grep`'s ignore option too here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I still gives all the lines as output. I added two more screenshots that may help. Could it be that the file is the problem, since it worked when you tested it? The file was created on windows, maybe there is the issue?

Comment: @thepaintedcow, looks like you have carriage returns in your Input_file, can you run once `cat -v Input_file` in your file and let me know if you see control M characters there?

Comment: I have tried it, see the updated post above. Still it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: @thepaintedcow, `awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{gsub(/\r/,"")} FNR==1{print;next} !/C:\\Windows\\system32\\/' Input_file` has worked for me, didn't it work for you? For your shown samples please do let know here not in question please.

Comment: @thepaintedcow, check what `awk '!/C:\\Windows\\system32/' Input_file` do?

Comment: From what I see it filters out some lines but not all of them. The original file had 150 lines not there are only 68. But still there are lines with C:\\Windows\\system32.

Comment: Ok I got it. There are two directories one is system32 and the other one System32. Because its case sensitive, the second path was not filtered.

Comment: @thepaintedcow, looks like your `awk` is NOT having `IGNORECASE` could you please try `awk '!/[cC]:\\[wW][iI][nN][dD][[oO][wW][sS]\\[sS][yY][sS][tT][eE][mM]32/' Input_file` once? This should work I believe.

Comment: @thepaintedcow, Your welcome. if you would have shown your samples at very first I would have made it s a dupe, this should be a common question, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: `!/[cC]:\\[wW][iI][nN][dD][[oO][wW][sS]\\[sS][yY][sS][tT][eE][mM]32/` should be written as just `tolower($0) !~ /c:\\windows\\system32/`.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir I have added it now thanks a TON, cheers